# Unable to disable everyone ping in webhook -discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, webhooks

why the code dont work???

i do the code without  if '@' in message.content:
pass
else:

and its work but pepole can do @everyone

so i add

i do the code without  if '@' in message.content:
pass
else:

and is dont work plz help

```
#fake
@bot.command()
async def fake(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message="plz type message"):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  webhooks = await ctx.channel.webhooks()
  for webhook in webhooks:
      await webhook.delete()
  webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=member.name)
  if '@' in message.content:
    pass
  else:
    await webhook.send(str(message), username=member.name, avatar_url=member.avatar_url)
```

Comment: Do you want to only have it without the everyone role or without all roles?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove all `everyone` and `here` mentions by changing allowed mentions.

```py
webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=member.name)
await webhook.send(str(message), username=member.name, avatar_url=member.avatar_url, allowed_mentions=discord.AllowedMentions(everyone=False))
```

### References:

- [webhook.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhook%20send#discord.Webhook.send)
- [AllowedMentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhook%20send#discord.AllowedMentions)